# Can I read the whole char* in one call of sscanf?

Tags: c++, file-io, scanf

I try to parse a large char* to double values via sscanf.

When I loop threw the lines (4 double values) sscanf needs a lot of time.

```
while(sscanf(buffer, "%lf %lf %lf %lf%n", &d1,&d2,&d3,&d4,&n))
{
... do some stuff with d1 ... d4
buffer += n;
}
```

But when I scan 4 lines at a time its nearly 4 times faster:

```
while(sscanf(buffer, "%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf%n", &d1,&d2,&d3,&d4,&d5,&d6,&d7,&d8,&d9,&d10,&d11,&d12,&d13,&d14,&d15,&d16,&n))
{
    ... do some stuff with d1 ... d16
    buffer += n;
}
```

Is there a way to scan all the values at one time?

I know the length of the array, but its not fixed (depends on the file that I try to read).

thanks!

Comment: `char*` and `sscanf` seems like you are writing C code. If this is really C++ you would be using `std::string`, `std::stringstream` and others. Can you clearify?

Comment: *When I loop threw the lines (4 double values) sscanf needs a lot of time* -- You didn't post the command-line options you used to test your results.  If you're testing an unoptimized or "debug" version, the results you are seeing are not valid tests.  Second, what if there are 1,000 numbers?  Create 1,000 float variables and use a string with 1,000 "%lf"'s in it?

Comment: The problem with `sscanf` is that it requires a run-time parsing of the format string. `istream& operator(istream&, double&)` does not.

Comment: have you heard of stod http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/? Its C++11 though.

Comment: Eichhörnchen: yes i'm writing c++ (even if i'm using a char array)                                PaulMcKenzie: yes i compiled in release mode and optimzed for speed.      MSalters: I'll try that, thanks!                                                                                       ladaManiak: I've heard of it, but stod only handles one double at a time!?

Comment: You need to add `@` in front of usernames if you want them to be notified of your answer. As I mentioned you really shouldn't be using `sscanf` in C++ code, for safety, style and, as MSalters said, performance reasons. You should put your C-style string into a `std::string`, create a `std::stringstream` from it and then read out one double at a time with `>>`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  yes i compiled in release mode and optimzed for speed.

Comment: @ladaManiak: I've heard of it, but stod only handles one double at a time!?